# A Bounded Continuous Function on a Circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous and:
$$
|f(e^{i \theta})| \leq M
$$

Suppose:
$$
|\int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz| = 2\pi M
$$
I am trying to show that $f(z) = c \bar{z}$ for some constant $c$ with $|c|=M$

[image]

Comment: Liouville's theorem?

Comment: Hi Paul, that theorem is valid for entire bounded functions. I think the asker meant that f is bounded on the unit circle.

Comment: @RedPhoenix That's strange because I have double checked question from the textbook. Which part of the question do you think is wrong?

Comment: @RedPhoenix: No, the closed integral over a constant function vanishes.

Comment: I attached the picture of the question in the textbook (Gamelin's)

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos sorry friend, I skipped Cauchy thm. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos the nonzero value implies the existence of a sing value right?

Comment: Your picture displays a running title with "for analytic functions".  Is $f$ assumed to be analytic, and if so, in what domain?  Is it a domain that is simply connected and containing the unit circle?  If so, you want (Schwarz's Lemma)[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma ]

Comment: @RedPhoenix: it would, if $f$ were be assumed to be analytic on some open set containing the unit circle. But it's only assumed to be continuous, and isn't even defined outside the circle, so all the theorems of complex analysis can't be applied, unless there is a known holomorphic extension of the function. But the task essentially boils down to proving that such an extension exists (since $c\bar z$ has a holomorphic extension in the form of $\frac cz$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=\alpha|\int_{|z|=1}f(z)dz|, |\alpha|=1$; also note that $dz=iz|dz|$ on the unit circle

$2\pi M=\int_{|z|=1}\alpha^{-1} f(z)dz= \int_{|z|=1}\alpha^{-1} if(z)z|dz| \le  \int_{|z|=1}|\alpha^{-1} if(z)z||dz| = \int_{|z|=1}|f(z)||dz| \le 2\pi M$ so we have equality (ae and then everywhere by continuity).

But $|dz|$ is a positive measure so this first means that $|f(z)|=M$ on the unit circle and then by taking real and imaginary parts that  $\Re \alpha^{-1} if(z)z=|f(z)|=M, \Im \alpha^{-1} if(z)z=0$ hence $f(z)=-i\alpha M/z=-i\alpha M \bar z$ so we are done!

Comment: @Could you explain more why $dz=iz|dz|$ on the unit circle? because I found $dz=izd \theta$

Comment: Because on the unit circle $|dz|=d\theta$ the arclength; in general of course $|dz|=Rd\theta$ when the circle has radius $R$